# How to make 3 divs space evenly apart --- 2 on top, 1 on bottom

Tags: html, css

Refer to image: I am trying to figure out how I can horizontally space 3 divs equally apart with 2 being on top and one on the bottom. The "x" in the image should all be equal as the page resizes.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: flexbox is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative, using CSS Grid may help you reason about the code a little bit easier so I've provided this answer as an alternative to flexbox for learning purposes, although [support for CSS Grid](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) is not perfect yet

(See the pen to view this live: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mXBqWZ )

---

Assuming this markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item1"></div>
  <div class="item item2"></div>
  <div class="item item3"></div>
</div>
```

We can style this with CSS Grid as such:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 300px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 150px);
  grid-column-gap: 75px;     /* where x = 75px */
  grid-row-gap: 50px;        /* or whatever you like */

  border: 5px solid red;     /* for clarity on padding */
  padding: 25px 75px 25px 75px;
}
```

Comment: If you're interested in this approach, maybe see also [this great article](https://www.chenhuijing.com/blog/how-i-design-with-css-grid/#%F0%9F%8F%80) breaking down the thought process of designing content to work easily in CSS Grid for the next time you work with grid

Comment: Sorry, why the downvote? If you truly think the answer is not helpful, I'd be happy to revise it if you can clarify how this doesn't fit your needs.

Answer (score -3):

Using Flexbox:

The 4th item is hidden because if you don't do that the space-evenly will fail for the 3rd item.

```css
.main-container {
  overflow: auto;
}

.item-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.item--hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
    <div class="item item--hidden">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using Calc:

This is more complicated, but it offers more support for IE10&IE11 and partial support for IE9.
For more information: [Calc browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

```css
.main-container {
  overflow:auto;
}

.item-container {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.item-container:nth-child(odd) > .item
{
    margin-left: calc((100% - 300px) * (2 / 3));
}
.item-container:nth-child(even) > .item
{
    margin-left: calc((100% - 300px) * (1 / 3));
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item-container">
    <div class="item">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: after that much calculation where is evenly space ?

Comment: Could you be little bit more precise with your question? I am not sure what you're asking. When you open both examples(Flexbox & Calc) in full page the result is identical.

Comment: Why the down vote? It does exactly what OP wants. If it's not clear let me know.

Comment: Well I did not down voted your answer, but my question is that op want a evenly spacing of `x` in his diagram and that is responsive.

Comment: He never mentioned that it has to be responsive.

Comment: Buddy find this line in question `The "x" in the image should all be equal as the page resizes.`

Comment: When you're using the Calc version the `x` becomes 0 on all places when you're on small devices, which means `x` is equal. As for the Flexbox method when your on a small device you should switch the flex direction to column, but this has nothing to do with OP his question.